# Teradata SQL with non-aggregated fields in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I have the code below that the Teradata will not work, and return the message as 'Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.' I think I have made sure all non-aggregated fields have been put in GROUP BY Clauses already. Can you help me take a look why its not working?

```
SELECT  str.store,str.city, str.state, dep.deptdesc, 100*(Clean.DecSales/Clean.DecSaleDays-Clean.NovSales/Clean.NovSaleDays)/(Clean.NovSales/Clean.NovSaleDays) AS PercentageChange

FROM ((skuinfo sku LEFT JOIN deptinfo dep ON sku.dept=dep.dept)

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT t.sku, t.store, COUNT(DISTINCT t.saledate) AS NumOfDays, SUM(t.amt) AS DailyTotal,

(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.saledate) AS VARCHAR(8)))||'.'||
      (CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.saledate) AS VARCHAR(8)))||'.'||
      (CAST(t.store AS VARCHAR(8)))AS ComboID,

SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH from t.saledate) =11 THEN t.Amt END) AS NovSales,

SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH from t.saledate) =12 THEN t.Amt END) AS DecSales,

COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH from t.saledate) =11 THEN t.saledate END) AS NovSaleDays,

COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH from t.saledate) =12 THEN t.saledate END) AS DecSaleDays

FROM trnsact t

WHERE (t.saledate NOT BETWEEN '2005-08-01' AND '2005-08-31') AND t.stype='P'

GROUP BY t.sku, t.store

HAVING NumOfDays>19) Clean 

ON sku.sku=Clean.sku)

LEFT JOIN strinfo str ON str.store=Clean.store

GROUP BY str.store,str.city, str.state, dep.deptdesc;
```

Comment: Put the expression PercentageChange in a SUM or put in in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` on the outer query. Replace `GROUP BY` in the derived table `Clean` with an ordinal `GROUP BY 1, 2, 5`.

Something makes me believe the derived table's column `ComboID`, composed of `SaleDate` and `StoreID` because `SaleDate` is not part of the `GROUP BY` but is participating elsewhere in an aggregate of the derived table.

Answer (score 1):

This is your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT str.store, str.city, str.state, dep.deptdesc,
       (100*(Clean.DecSales/Clean.DecSaleDays-Clean.NovSales/Clean.NovSaleDays)/(Clean.NovSales/Clean.NovSaleDays) ) AS PercentageChange
```

This is your `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY str.store, str.city, str.state, dep.deptdesc
```

I see lots of column references in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  I would guess that you intend either `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT str.store, str.city, str.state, dep.deptdesc,
       SUM(100*(Clean.DecSales/Clean.DecSaleDays-Clean.NovSales/Clean.NovSaleDays)/(Clean.NovSales/Clean.NovSaleDays)
          ) AS PercentageChange
```

Or no `GROUP BY` at all in the outer query.